# What is wrong with the piece of XSLT code

Tags: xslt-1.0

Just started coding. Attribute value setting does not seem to work and the child nodes of the reference node in the outer for-each loop are not accessed. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <B2BGatewayDoc>
      <Document>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/B2BGatewayDoc/Document/ServiceHeader" />
        <ServiceContent>
          <Transmission>
            <TransmissionBody>
              <xsl:copy-of select="/B2BGatewayDoc/Document/ServiceContent/Transmission/TransmissionBody/ReceiverSystem" />
              <xsl:for-each select="/B2BGatewayDoc/Document/ServiceContent/Transmission/TransmissionBody/GLogXMLElement" >
                <GLogXMLElement>
                  <ActualShipment>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmlns" >
                      <xsl:value-of select="ActualShipment/@xmlns" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <Shipment>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="ActualShipment/Shipment/ShipmentHeader" />
                      <xsl:for-each select="ActualShipment/Shipment/TransOrder" >
                        <TransOrder>
                          <xsl:copy-of select="TransOrderHeader" />
                        </TransOrder>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </Shipment>
                  </ActualShipment>
                </GLogXMLElement>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </TransmissionBody>
          </Transmission>
        </ServiceContent>
      </Document>
    </B2BGatewayDoc>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML Sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<B2BGatewayDoc>
  <Document>
    <ServiceHeader>
      <Protocol name="ANSIX12">
        <Sender>941714834TEST</Sender>
        <Receiver>003897733SAPT</Receiver>
        <MsgType>3A4MG2</MsgType>
        <ReferenceNumber/>
        <PipVersion>V02.02</PipVersion>
        <InstanceIdentifier/>
      </Protocol>
    </ServiceHeader>
    <ServiceContent>
      <Transmission>
        <TransmissionBody>
          <ReceiverSystem>
            <ReceiverSystemName>XXXXX</ReceiverSystemName>
            <ReceiverSystemName>YYYYY</ReceiverSystemName>
          </ReceiverSystem>
          <GLogXMLElement>
            <ActualShipment xmlns="1000181ZZZ">
              <Shipment>
                <ShipmentHeader>
                  <ShipmentGid>
                    <Gid>
                      <Xid>1000181ZZZ</Xid>
                    </Gid>
                  </ShipmentGid>
                  <ShipmentRefnum>
                    <ShipmentRefnumQualifierGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid>SELLER_INV_NBR</Xid>
                      </Gid>
                    </ShipmentRefnumQualifierGid>
                    <ShipmentRefnumValue>VALUE 1</ShipmentRefnumValue>
                  </ShipmentRefnum>
                  <ShipmentRefnum>
                    <ShipmentRefnumQualifierGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid>SHIP_TYPE</Xid>
                      </Gid>
                    </ShipmentRefnumQualifierGid>
                    <ShipmentRefnumValue>O</ShipmentRefnumValue>
                  </ShipmentRefnum>
                  <TransactionCode>IU</TransactionCode>
                  <TotalShipUnitCount>1</TotalShipUnitCount>
                  <TotalPackagedItemSpecCount>1</TotalPackagedItemSpecCount>
                  <CommercialTerms>
                    <IncoTermGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid>EXW</Xid>
                      </Gid>
                    </IncoTermGid>
                  </CommercialTerms>
                  <NumOrderReleases>1</NumOrderReleases>
                  <VesselGid>
                    <Gid>
                      <Xid>BOL54891</Xid>
                    </Gid>
                  </VesselGid>
                </ShipmentHeader>
                <TransOrder>
                  <TransOrderHeader>
                    <TransOrderGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid>BR20000238</Xid>
                      </Gid>
                    </TransOrderGid>
                    <CommercialTerms>
                      <IncoTermGid>
                        <Gid>
                          <Xid>EXW</Xid>
                        </Gid>
                      </IncoTermGid>
                    </CommercialTerms>
                    <TransportModeGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid>H</Xid>
                      </Gid>
                    </TransportModeGid>
                    <ModeProfileGid>
                      <Gid>
                        <Xid/>
                      </Gid>
                    </ModeProfileGid>
                    <OrderRefnum>
                      <OrderRefnumQualifierGid>
                        <Gid>
                          <Xid>BOL</Xid>
                        </Gid>
                      </OrderRefnumQualifierGid>
                      <OrderRefnumValue>BOL54891</OrderRefnumValue>
                    </OrderRefnum>
                    <OrderRefnum>
                      <OrderRefnumQualifierGid>
                        <Gid>
                          <Xid>CUST_PO_NBR</Xid>
                        </Gid>
                      </OrderRefnumQualifierGid>
                      <OrderRefnumValue>4700175047</OrderRefnumValue>
                    </OrderRefnum>
                    <TotalNetWeightVolume>
                      <Weight>
                        <WeightValue>18.9</WeightValue>
                        <WeightUOMGid>
                          <Gid>
                            <Xid>KG</Xid>
                          </Gid>
                        </WeightUOMGid>
                      </Weight>
                      <Volume>
                        <VolumeValue>0</VolumeValue>
                        <VolumeUOMGid>
                          <Gid>
                            <Xid>CR</Xid>
                          </Gid>
                        </VolumeUOMGid>
                      </Volume>
                    </TotalNetWeightVolume>
                  </TransOrderHeader>
                </TransOrder>
              </Shipment>
            </ActualShipment>
          </GLogXMLElement>
        </TransmissionBody>
      </Transmission>
    </ServiceContent>
  </Document>
</B2BGatewayDoc>
```

### The output I get

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<B2BGatewayDoc>
  <Document>
    <ServiceHeader>
      <Protocol name="ANSIX12">
        <Sender>941714834TEST</Sender>
        <Receiver>003897733SAPT</Receiver>
        <MsgType>3A4MG2</MsgType>
        <ReferenceNumber/>
        <PipVersion>V02.02</PipVersion>
        <InstanceIdentifier/>
      </Protocol>
    </ServiceHeader>
    <ServiceContent>
      <Transmission>
        <TransmissionBody>
          <ReceiverSystem>
            <ReceiverSystemName>XXXXX</ReceiverSystemName>
            <ReceiverSystemName>YYYYY</ReceiverSystemName>
          </ReceiverSystem>
          <GLogXMLElement>
            <ActualShipment xmlns="">
              <Shipment/>
            </ActualShipment>
          </GLogXMLElement>
        </TransmissionBody>
      </Transmission>
    </ServiceContent>
  </Document>
</B2BGatewayDoc>
```

Attribute `xmlns` is not assigned a value though the source value is availale. All nodes and tags within tag `Shipment` do not get created.

Any pointer to reason is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the formal error, Visual Studio says, *An attribute with a local name 'xmlns' and a null namespace URI cannot be created*. Which makes sense - you don't create namespaces like this.

Even if you could dynamically generate a namespace for your output, it would still not work because your XSL template would not be able to query the data file. In your data you have `<ActualShipment xmlns="1000181ZZZ">`, so all nodes under `ActualShipment` have the namespace `1000181ZZZ`, and you have to put that namespace into your XSL. Otherwise the XSL looks for nodes with a blank namespace and does not find any -- all nodes have a namespace of `1000181ZZZ`. To query that from an XSL, you would need to add `xmlns:something="1000181ZZZ"` to the declaration of your `<xsl:stylesheet>`:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:something="1000181ZZZ">
```

and then use it in the xPath like this:

```xml
<Shipment>
  <xsl:copy-of select="something:ActualShipment/something:Shipment/something:ShipmentHeader" />
  <xsl:for-each select="something:ActualShipment/something:Shipment/something:TransOrder" >
    <TransOrder>
      <xsl:copy-of select="something:TransOrderHeader" />
    </TransOrder>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Shipment>
```

You shouldn't be using namespaces like variables. They are supposed to be known in advance.

An obvious fix is to replace `<ActualShipment xmlns="1000181ZZZ">` with something like `<ActualShipment some_attribute="1000181ZZZ">`.

Comment: Hello GSerg,Thanks a lot. I had overlooked that aspect. The problem is the XML has it in all cases. This has to be bypassed. I am trying all possibilities and have gone through numerous blogs but nothing productive has emerged. How can it be bypassed? I keep trying.